# can we give <div> within <li>

Tags: html

```
<li><div>blablabla</div></li>
```

Is it Possible

Comment: Not really on topic for this site. Questions should be about ui *design* rather than ui *implementation*.

Comment: doctype.com would be a better place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, however, I don't know if it's correct to do it I'm afraid.